# How to properly enable comments form in page template

Tags: pages, comments, comment-form

I've applied the following code to enable the comment section in the page template.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                        <div class="sec-text wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="300ms" data-wow-duration="1000ms">
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </article>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <?php
                if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                    comments_template();
                endif;
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();?>
            </div>
```

The comment form is showing directly by this code. User can not able to disable or re-enable the comment form in editor for specific page.

Comment: Did you mean "Discussion" metabox not exist to checklist allow comments?

Comment: No, the "Discussion" metabox is showing in page editor as well. When I uncheck or check the "Allow comments", this doesn't work. 
I can not able to disable the comment form by unchecking "Allow comments".

Comment: This issue could be from anywhere. I suggest you to check if default page doing like so or you can switch to default theme, then create page template https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/ , check if the issue still exist.

Comment: I checked my comment related functions and I found a cuprite filter. I deleted this filter and now my comment form is working as well.
The filter is is -
add_filter( 'comments_open', 'my_comments_open', 10, 2 );
function my_comments_open( $open, $post_id ) {
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    if ( 'page' == $post->post_type )
        $open = true;
    return $open;
}

Comment: Great!. After you can solve your issue, maybe you need to update your question and mark it as answered. Please take your time to read this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

I think it *could* be a problem with `get_comments_number` which returns numeric, though theoretically it should test this way too... you could try instead:

```
if ( comments_open() || have_comments() ) :
    comments_template();
endif;
```

OR

```
if ( comments_open() || (get_comments_number() > 0) ) :
    comments_template();
endif;
```

Comment: It should be have_comments() instead of has_comments(). I tried has_comments, it gave me errors. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/have_comments/

Comment: thanks for that, I have edited the answer to use `have_comments` now

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do that for specific pages like with a page of page id 9

```
 //for single page
 if(is_page(9)){ 
  //execute comment template
  comments_template( '', true );

   }

//for single post
if(is_single(9)){
  comments_template( '', true );

}
```

Comment: I don't want to enable comment form for the specific pages. I just want to enable the comment form for every page properly.
Please read the question as well.